# Rails converting string with float value to integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that has an attribute named `value` this is saved in the db as an `integer`.

I input the number in the view using a `text_field`, I am also performing a method on it `:before_save` that takes the value (something like 21.37) and using the `money` gem convert it to just cents.

However, it seems that before I can even perform the method that converts it from a float to an integer it is being converted to some kind of integer and the decimal is being lost.

I have tested this by outputting `value` in the method that runs `before_save:` and it round it to `21`

Does anyone know why this might be happening, Im not performing any other changes to it.

Comment: In your server log, is `param[:value]` 21.37 or 21? I'm wondering if the rounding happens in Rails or Rack.

Comment: Looking back through the logs I am seeing this 
Started POST "/projects/1/coupons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-21 19:09:55 +0000
Processing by CouponsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: { "value"=>"12.28"} So looks like it is keeping it as a string initially I assume it must be a Rails thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're doing something like `Coupon.new(params)` in your controller, and since Rails knows `Coupon`'s `value` should be an integer, it helpfully calls `to_i` on `params[:value]` for you under the covers, which turns 21.37 into 21. Here's a rather inelegant but effective fix:

```
params[:value] ~= /.*\.(\d+)/
params[:value] = params[:value].to_f * (10**$1.length) if $1
```

Do that before you do `Coupon.new(params)`.

Another option is to simply assume you don't care about anything after the 2nd decimal place (you're dealing with cents after all). Then you can simply do `params[:value] = params[:value].to_f.round(2) * 100`.

Also you should consider using `number_field` instead of `text_field` in your view so you can at least be sure you're getting a number. Something like `number_field(:coupon, :value, step: 0.01)` should ensure your users can enter decimals.

Comment: Yeah I assumed it would be something like that unfortunately I never know for sure if the number will have 2 decimal places

Comment: I added a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kitkat seems like something that would happen in the model layer. You might be able to implement your conversion to cents logic in 'before_validation' or perhaps a custom setter for 'coupon'.